# How do i get webdriver to see elements in included html files

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to located elements that is in an html file that is included into my main app.

When i try to use driver.findElement(by.className('name')) , it says element not found.

```
<div>
                <!-- ngInclude: 'scripts/pageTabs/pageTabs.html' --><div ng-include="'scripts/pageTabs/pageTabs.html'" class="ng-scope"><div ng-controller="callCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<div class="page-tabs">
    <div title="Directory" id="dirTab" ui-sref="landing.directory" class="page-tab" ng-class="{selected: $state.includes('landing.directory')}" href="#/landing/directory">
        <span class="page-tab-icon icon-directory"></span>
        <span class="page-tab-text ng-binding">Directory</span>
    </div>
    <div title="Conversations" id="actCommTab" ui-sref="landing.activity" class="page-tab" ng-class="{selected: $state.includes('landing.activity')}" href="#/landing/activity">
        <span class="page-tab-icon icon-conversations"></span>
        <div class="activeCount ng-binding">(0)</div>
        <span class="page-tab-text ng-binding">Conversations</span>
    </div>
    <div title="History" ui-sref="landing.notifications" class="page-tab selected" ng-class="{selected: $state.includes('landing.notifications')}" href="#/landing/notifications">
        <span class="page-tab-icon icon-history"></span>
        <span class="page-tab-text ng-binding">History</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

i am trying to click() the tag ''title=History'' , but webdriver says it cant find that element, am i doing it right?

Comment: You probably need to wait for stuff to load.

Comment: i've added `browser.sleep(10000);` and i used `browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName('History')).click();` is that right , but it still says can't find element

Comment: Title != tag name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following (check the syntax if it is as per javascript):

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='History']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using any of below path, they should work:
By cssSelector
browser.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.page-tab.selected>span.page-tab-text.ng-binding")).click();
By xpath
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[[contains(@href,'#/landing/notifications') and @title='History']")).click();